# Joomla logout with message

Tags: joomla, message-queue, logout

I'm trying to modify the

> 'Token Interceptor' system plugin

by [joomunited.com](http://www.joomunited.com)

The original plugin redirects on encountering an invalid token error using `register_shutdown_function`.

I'm trying to get it to:

1. Log the user out if they are logged in
2. Redirect to the login page with the invalid token message

Code:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
if (!JFactory::getUser()->guest)
{
    $app->logout();
}
$app->redirect('/index.php', JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'), 'warning');
```

I can successfully log the user out and redirect to the login page but the error message is not being displayed.

How can I retain the message after logging the user out?

i've also tried:

```
$app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'), 'warning');
```

but that didn't work either...

Comment: Try enque message option just above the $app->logout(); function.

Comment: @JobinJose Actually the message is not displayed even if I don't log the user out...

Comment: Just guessing here. You have system cache plugin enabled? you might be pulling the response page from the cache (thus without the message). Is this the case?

Comment: @RiccardoZorn No the plugin is not enabled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was a variation of Alonzo Turner's 2nd post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/WISy8JIvB8k).

The plugin redirects to the login page with a parameter passed in the url. The `onAfterInitialise` event then looks for this parameter and displays a message if it's found.

```
class PlgSystemTokeninterceptor extends JPlugin
{

    public function __construct(&$subject, $config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        if (($app->isSite() && $this->params->get('use_frontend')) || ($app->isAdmin() && $this->params->get('use_backend'))) 
        {
            register_shutdown_function(array($this,'redirectToLogin'));
        }

    }

    public function redirectToLogin()
    {
        $content = ob_get_contents();

        if($content == JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN') || $content == 'Invalid Token')
        {
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();

            if (!JFactory::getUser()->guest)
            {
                $app->logout();
            }

            $app->redirect(JURI::base().'index.php?invalid_token=true');

            return false;   
        }
    }

    function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $invalid_token = $app->input->get('invalid_token', 'false');

        if ($invalid_token == 'true')
        {
            $app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'), 'warning');
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you logout you destroy the session so you are not going to have the message any more.

This will get you a message on redirect.

```
$this->redirect = JUri::base() . 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login';    
if (!JFactory::getUser()->guest && $app->input->getCmd('option') != 'com_users')

{
    $app->enqueueMessage('message', 'warning');
    //$app->logout();
    $app->redirect($this->redirect);

}
```

This will not because the session is destroyed

```
$this->redirect = JUri::base() . 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login';    
if (!JFactory::getUser()->guest && $app->input->getCmd('option') != 'com_users')

{
    $app->enqueueMessage('message', 'warning');
    $app->logout();
    $app->redirect($this->redirect);

}
```

Not tested but

```
$app->logout()
echo '<div class="">'. JText::_('whatever you want') . '</div>'; 
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('login');
$output = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

Something like that

Comment: Is there any way to pass the message? Alonzo Turner describes a method in his second post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/WISy8JIvB8k but I couldn't get this to work with `JInput`

Comment: Well that is using a systemplugin ... instead of doing all of this why  don't you just render a message and the login module in place if the token is bad? That seems much simpler to me.

Comment: Sorry Elin I'm not sure I follow, would you mind elaborating on that a bit? I must say I was surprised how long winded the plugin solution turned out to be to get an invalid token exception to redirect to the login page so I'd be very interested if your suggestion is easier?

Comment: if you want to log them out and have them log back in, use the Module api and render the login module in the page rather than the content. And you can render a message right there styling it to look like a regular system message if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The only problem is that I need to redirect from an invalid token exception and the only way I could see how to do that was with `register_shutdown_function` in a plugin...